# split_part in Redshift to get last value after parsing

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am interested in getting the last item from the `split_part` function result.

If the `field1` has:

```
abc : def : ghi : jkl
abc : def : ghi : jkl : lmn
```

`split_part(reverse(field1), ':', 1)` did not work because it returned:

```
lkj
nml
```

I wanted it to return:

```
jkl
lmn
```

Answer (score 12):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
reverse(split_part(reverse(field1), ':', 1));
```

You can also consider creating a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_split_part(varchar(65535), varchar(1), int)
RETURNS varchar(65535)
AS
$$
SELECT
    reverse(split_part(reverse($1), $2, $3));
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

And using it like this:

```
admin@dev# select reverse_split_part(field1, ':', 1) from tbl;
reverse_split_part 
--------------------
  jkl
  lmn
(2 rows)
```